# multiword method names/class vs separate class

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a small forum app where a **user** has a **profile** and on that profile, the user who owns the profile as well as other users, can make **posts** ( pretty much the same concept as with fb ).

My concern is whether it is better to have **multi-word classes** or whether it is better to have a **separate class for each word**.

For example, if i have a **profile** on which i can create **posts**.

- Would it be better to have a model **Profile** and a model **Posts**
- Or it is better to have a **ProfilePost** model

My approaches so far are the following

1. The tables for the first approach

```
users
- id

profile
- id
- user_id

posts
- id
- body
- profile_id

comments
- id
- body
- poster_id
- post_id
```

Where **poster** is the user who creates the **post**

- The **user** has a **profile**
- The **profile** has **posts**
- **Posts** have **comments**

As a result, if i want to add a new post, then i'd have to make multiple joins, for example

```
$user->profile()->posts()->addBy($anotherUser, $post)

$user->profile()->post($post)->addCommentBy($comment, $anotherUser)
```

2. The tables for the second approach are

```
users
- id

profile_posts
- id
- body
- profile_user_id
- poster_id

comments
- id
- poster_id
- profile_post_id
```

And the approach to create a post and a comment will be like

```
$user->postToProfile($profileUser, $post);
$user->profilePost($post)->addComment($comment);
```

- The **first** approach requires multiple joins but the naming seems more elegant to me.
- While the  **second** approach consists of multiwords such as **profilePost** which seems like these words can be extracted into their own classes.

Comment: If a user just has one profile then there is no need for the profile table/model. So you just need User, Post and Comment models. A User has many Post and a Post has many Comment.

Comment: i just wanted to describe better the relationships. because the term post is quite general. In a forum app, there are threads and replies which can also be considered posts.

Comment: I recommend sticking with Laravel naming convention, as it makes developing easier for you. You can use a single eloquent model for posts and threads and each model (record) has a type.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part. ` You can use a single eloquent model for posts and threads and each model (record) has a type. ` . Could you please explain what do you mean by "each model has a type" ?

Comment: Are you talking about polymorphic relationship ?